decorate function and method with same decorator
I have a function, a class implementing the similar method and a decorator. The current decorator signature does allow it to be used for the function but doesn't work with the method as expected.
from functools import wraps

def nice(f):
   @wraps(f)
   def decorator(a, b):
       result = f(a, b)
       return 'result is: %s' % str(result)
   
   return decorator

@nice
def sumup(a, b):
   return a + b


class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   
   @nice
   def sumup(self, a, b):
       return a + b

print(sumup(2, 6))
cls = Test()
print(cls.sumup(4, 8))

Can I somehow 'overload' decorator? In C++ I would be able to write the same decorator again with the same name but different signature and it would work. Can I use some nice solutions in this case? Or I need to just add the same decorator with different name like:
def nice_cls(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, a, b):
        result = f(self, a, b)
        return 'result is: %s' % str(result)
    
    return decorator

and use it for the method?

How about def decorator(*args)?

@PaulM. Holly cow...... thaths fckng brilliand:) I didn't came to this thought....
